# Detect side of the page with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I want to define a macro `\mymark` to produce a simple small `tikzpicture` in the margin, on the side that is closest to the point in the text where the macro was called.

What I have so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\markshift}
\setlength{\markshift}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\markshift}{-\textwidth}
\setlength{\markshift}{.5\markshift}
\addtolength{\markshift}{-.5cm}


\newcommand{\mymark}{%
  \textbf{MARK}% just to see where the measurement is taken
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-2.5pt]{
    \coordinate(mymark);
    \path let \p1 = (current page.north), \p2 = (mymark) in \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathparse{(\x1-\x2)>0 ? "west" : "east"}
      \global\let\mymarkside\pgfmathresult
      \pgfmathparse{(\x1-\x2)>0 ? \markshift : -\markshift}
      \global\let\mymarkoffset\pgfmathresult
    };
  }%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill(mymark -| current page.\mymarkside) ++(\mymarkoffset pt,0)
      circle[radius=3pt];%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\mymark
\lipsum*[4]
\mymark
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This works just fine but feels fiddly (all the `pgfextra` and `\global` business seems redundant).
Is there a more direct way to achieve the same result?

[image: example]

Comment: do you try `\marginpar`?

Comment: @Zarko I know of `\marginpar` and my goal is not to use it. One of the reasons is that I want to control how marks on the same line get pushed around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is exactly what `\pgfextra{}` is for (well alright maybe not *exactly*, but you know what I mean). It is possible to make your code slightly shorter however.

Firstly, you don't need `\coordinate (mymark)`, because its location is always `(0,0)`. For the same reason, you only have to check whether `\x1` is bigger than 0. Also, you don't need the `\global`s if you stay within one pgf scope. This also means that you don't need `\mymarkoffset` at all.

Complete code (which results in the same screenshot as you posted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\markshift}
\setlength{\markshift}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\markshift}{-\textwidth}
\setlength{\markshift}{.5\markshift}
\addtolength{\markshift}{-.5cm}

\newcommand{\mymark}{%
    \textbf{MARK}% just to see where the measurement is taken
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-2.5pt]{
        \fill let \p1 = (current page.north) in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathparse{\x1>0 ? "west" : "east"}
            \let\mymarkside\pgfmathresult
            \pgfmathparse{\x1>0 ? 1 : -1}
        } (0,0 -| current page.\mymarkside) ++(\pgfmathresult*\markshift,0) circle[radius=3pt];
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\mymark
\lipsum*[4]
\mymark
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**
With some help from @percusse, it's nearly becoming a one-liner:

```
\newcommand{\mymark}{%
    \textbf{MARK}% just to see where the measurement is taken
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-2.5pt]{
        \fill[black] let \p1=(current page.north), \n1={\x1 > 0 ? 180 : 0} in (0,0 -| current page.\n1) ++ (\n1+180:\markshift) circle[radius=3pt];
    }%
}
```

With still the same result.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Comment: Instead of `pgfextra` you can still keep adding constants with `\fill let \p1 = (current page.north),\n1 = {\x1>0 ? 180 : 0},\n2 = {\x1>0 ? 1 : -1} in...`